# Install Silverlight to TorBrowser on MacOSX

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I know the risks of doing this but that's what I need. I'm trying to play videos from netflix but the TorBrowser keeps telling me that I need to install Silverlight.exe which in MacOS is not possible of course.

I have installed Silverlight for FireFox and I know TorBrowser engine's come from Firefox, so I thought that by having installed it in that browser would show up somehow in TorBrower... **no love here.**

My next attempt was to try to move Silverlight.plugin (/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/) but couldn't find where to drop it inside TorBrowser. I tried several places but didn't work either.

I'm also trying to find the xpi file (if any exists) for Silverlight as I think I could load it in TorBrowser, but again, haven't been able to find any xpi for Silverlight... **still no love.**

Any help or pointers with useful information about how to install Silverlight or something that netflix can recognize to play movies will be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe Tor Browser has a hardcoded patch to reject plugins, so this will not be possible. I'll find a reference to the patch for you.

Comment: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/3547

Comment: FWIW, I remember Netflix was starting to block VPNs, proxies, and Tor, so you might not be able to watch Netflix anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly disabled by default, and has been for some years.

[#3547](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/3547) set about to block the loading of plugins to Tor Browser. For reasons I cannot fathom, an explicit exception is set for Flash. This is implemented through [this patch](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/commit/?h=tor-browser-45.6.0esr-6.5-1&id=de2eb8f8d9f0d4e1d7371a2204c78d68fc82a762).

[#10280](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10280) also enforces that the user has to explicitly enable even looking for flash, by unticking a box under the Tor Button's Privacy and Security settings page. This is implemented through [this patch](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor-browser.git/commit/?h=tor-browser-45.6.0esr-6.5-1&id=2d728f7c3a526d3b18fe4f61ad26ab0db316fcab).

As such you will, by design, have great difficulty adding any plugins into Tor Browser.

It has been suggested that trying to rename the plugin to appear as flash may work but understand that it is likely that the plugin may disregard the browsers proxy settings and an attacker may be able to utilise this to link your Tor browsing to your real identity and location *in unexpected and unanticipated ways*. Simply loading the plugin into the address space of the Tor Browser process may be enough to compromise your anonymity.